# d3 text function on a selection giving undefined

Tags: d3.js

I am doing [this](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/#index) exercise, and notice that the **text** function in the 3rd line below is alerting **undefined**. The parameter **i** is giving the number as expected. But why is **d** undefined? Does **d** not represent that particular **td** element? If not what does it(d parameter in the text call back function) actually represent?

```
var td = d3.selectAll("#tableTrial tbody tr").selectAll("td");
td.style("color", function (d, i) { return i ? null : "red"; });
td.text(function (d, i) { alert(d); return i;});
myFactory.drawd3Dia();
```

If I change that 3rd line to this

```
td.text(function (i) { alert(i); return i;});
```

**i** is comming out to be undefined.

The fulll HTML for the above is as follows. Just past in a text file and view in browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.12/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function () {
            'use strict';

            function myController($scope, $controller) {
                var td = d3.selectAll("#tableTrial tbody tr").selectAll("td");
                td.style("color", function (d, i) { return i ? null : "red"; });
                td.text(function (d, i) { alert(d); return i;});
                // If the above line is replaced with the following it again does not work.
                // td.text(function (i) { alert(i); return i;});
            }

            angular.module('myApp', []);
            angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);
            myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$controller'];

        }())
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-app="myApp">
        <div data-ng-controller="myController">
            <h1>Happy New Year :)</h1>
            <div id='tableTrial'>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr><td>  A</td><td>  B</td><td>  C</td><td>  D</td></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>  0</td><td>  1</td><td>  2</td><td>  3</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>  4</td><td>  5</td><td>  6</td><td>  7</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>  8</td><td>  9</td><td> 10</td><td> 11</td></tr>
                        <tr><td> 12</td><td> 13</td><td> 14</td><td> 15</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var td = d3.selectAll("#tableTrial tbody tr").selectAll("td"); After this line call td.data() this will return whatever the data associated with those objects. And whenever you call function(d,i){} in this that d represents to data associated with that object, here it is td object.

You might want to retrieve the data in td here you can access td.innerHTML, this will give you the data.

Comment: :( I tried td.text(function (d, i) { alert(d.innerHTML); return i; }); but no luck. I have even tried outerHTML with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is what is working finally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>My Angular App</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.12/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function () {
            'use strict';

            function myFactory($http) {
                var service = {
                    treeCollapse: CollpaseFunction,
                    drawd3Dia: D3DiagramFunction,
                    callParams: {}
                };

                return service;

                function D3DiagramFunction() { }

                function CollpaseFunction(c) { }
            }

            function myController($scope, $controller, myFactory) {

                var matrix = [
                  [10, 11, 12, 13],
                  [14, 15, 16, 17],
                  [18, 19, 110, 111],
                  [112, 113, 114, 115],
                ];

                var td = d3.selectAll("#tableTrial tbody tr")
                    //.selectAll("td")
                    .data(matrix)  //bind selection with data as mentioned in the blog post
                    //.enter() // use the enter selection
                    //.append("td"); // to append element on the page
                    .selectAll("td")
                    .data(function (d, i) { return d; })
                    .style("color", function (d, i) { return i ? null : "red"; })
                    .text(function (d, i) { return d; }) // now d is available since this selection is binded with data.
                ;
            }

            angular.module('myApp', []);
            angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', myFactory);
            myFactory.$inject = ['$http'];
            angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController);
            myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$controller', 'myFactory'];

        }())
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-ng-app="myApp">
        <div data-ng-controller="myController">
            <h1>Here we go...</h1>
            <div id='tableTrial'>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr><td>  A</td><td>  B</td><td>  C</td><td>  D</td></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr><td>  0</td><td>  1</td><td>  2</td><td>  3</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>  4</td><td>  5</td><td>  6</td><td>  7</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>  8</td><td>  9</td><td> 10</td><td> 11</td></tr>
                        <tr><td> 12</td><td> 13</td><td> 14</td><td> 15</td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind data to your selection so that `d` is available in callback function. In your case:

```
var matrix = [
  [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
  [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
  [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
  [12, 13, 14, 15],
];
var td = d3.selectAll("#tableTrial tbody tr").selectAll("td")
         .data(matrix)  //bind selection with data as mentioned in the blog post
         .enter() // use the enter selection
         .append("td") // to append element on the page
td.style("color", function (d, i) { return i ? null : "red"; }); 
td.text(function (d, i) { alert(d); return i;}); // now d is available since this selection is binded with data.
```

There are more info about selection in this [post](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)

Comment: Its still not working. Something wrong somewhere. I still working on it.